# How should I set up logger for Splunk in PingFederate?

Tags: splunk, pingfederate

I wish to set up PingFederate to log to Splunk.

Ping describes it nicely here https://ping.force.com/Support/Configuring-PingFederate-with-Splunk but the referenced sections to be uncommented can't be found in my PF instance -- it may have been removed before my time as part of a clean-up.

What should the contents of the log4j2.xml be?

I'm using PingFederate 8.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additional information on configuring PingFederate's log4j2.xml is available here: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=qst1564002981075.html

If you do not have a SecurityAudit2Splunk appender defined in your log4j2.xml, it should look something like:

```
   <RollingFile name="SecurityAudit2Splunk" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/splunk-audit.log"
        filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/splunk-audit.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d trackingid=&quot;%X{trackingid}&quot; event=%X{event} subject=&quot;%X{subject}&quot; ip=%X{ip} app=%X{app} connectionid=%X{connectionid} protocol=%X{protocol} pfhost=%X{host} role=%X{role} status=%X{status} adapterid=%X{adapterid} description=&quot;%X{description}&quot; responsetime=%X{responsetime} %n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

If you want to see an original log4j2.xml configuration file, you can always download PingFederate again to compare: https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/downloads/pingfederate.html

Also note that there is a PingFederate App for Splunk that can be a useful starting point for reporting: https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/976/

Comment: Excellent, precisely what I was looking for! Thanks for (speedy) reply!

Comment: Follow-up posted here -- in case you can help with that too ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203369/logging-from-ping-federate